# Linked Lists and Malloc

Tags: c

When creating a linked list in the following way, I understand everything that is happening except for:

```
curr = (item *)malloc(sizeof(item));
```

I get that you are allocating enough memory for the size of an item struct, but what exactly are you doing with (item *) ? Is this meant to be pointer notation or multiplication?

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>

struct list_el {
   int val;
   struct list_el * next;
};

typedef struct list_el item;

void main() {
   item * curr, * head;
   int i;

   head = NULL;

   for(i=1;i<=10;i++) {
      curr = (item *)malloc(sizeof(item));
      curr->val = i;
      curr->next  = head;
      head = curr;
   }

   curr = head;

   while(curr) {
      printf("%d\n", curr->val);
      curr = curr->next ;
   }
}
```

Comment: This is pointer notation. Assuming you don't know extreme C, using (item *) you are setting your pointer type to `item *` type after `alloc`ating block of memory of `item` size. And this is not multiplication, this is pointer. Read about `malloc` if it helps you (again, I am assuming you are new to C and have probably done other langs like C++/Java)

Comment: You should read about pointers and C. Your question here basically defies the existence of basic know how of powerful POINTERS.

Comment: In C, you don't cast the return value of malloc. See [c-faq 7.7b "What's wrong with casting malloc's return value? "](http://c-faq.com/malloc/mallocnocast.html) and [Do I cast the result of malloc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc). Secondly, don't tag a question as both C++ and C unless your specific question pertains to both languages.

Comment: Thank you hagubear, I understand, because malloc returns a void pointer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a pointer cast: it changes the `void*` return from `malloc` (a generic pointer) to an `item*` (a pointer of the specific type you need). A `void*` is a pointer that can point to anything, but you can't do any useful operations on it like indirection and arithmetic.

That said, the cast is [useless and considered bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc), because the C language guarantees that a `void*` will be converted to the right type automatically once you assign it. Just

```
curr = malloc(sizeof(item));
```

will do the trick and is less error-prone.

Comment: Less error-prone would be: `curr = malloc (sizeof *curr);`.

Answer (score 0):

The `(item *)` part is a type name (`item *` means "pointer to `item`") in parentheses, so it's a type cast.

They are used to convert between types, and [should *never* be used with `malloc()`'s return value like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc).